# How can i set a pytest mark to whole files?

Tags: pytest

I have a lot of test files (and subfolders) in tests directory.

How can I apply `pytest` `mark` to all files?

folders

```
tests/
. __init__.py
. test_aaaa.py
. test_bbbb.py
. ....
```

I don't want to add marks in each files.
Can I use pytest marks in `__init__.py` like this?

```
__init__.py

  import pytest
  pytest.mark.mymark
```

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/markers.html#marking-whole-classes-or-modules) you can do so by defining a `pytestmark` global variable

```
import pytest

pytestmark = pytest.mark.mymark
```

However, I would recommend applying inside of a `confest.py` rather than `__init__.py`